# IE8 first-child pseudo class on dynamic elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I am generating search results with AJAX and I am using the `first-child` pseudo class to remove `margin-top` from the first result. Unfortunately this class doesn't seem to work on IE8.

I am using `<!DOCTYPE html>` which is supposed to allow IE8 to accept first-child classes, but after doing some research, it appears as though applying the first-child class to elements which are inserted dynamically, does not work.

Does anyone know a quick and easy workaround for this? Thanks!

Remember, these divs are being generated dynamically, so manually adding a class to the first result div is out of the question, at least with straight HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are the results being fed? For browser compatibility, I would make the first item have a specific class, which can be targeted via CSS:

HTML:

```
  <div class="item first-item">Item One</div>
  <div class="item">second item</div>
  <div class="item">second item</div>
  <div class="item last-item">last item</div>
```

CSS:

```
  <style>
    .item { margin:8px 0; }
    .item.first-item { margin:0 0 8px; }
    .item.last-item { margin:8px 0 0; }
  </style>
```

Comment: They are being inserted dynamically via an AJAX call, so unfortunately I cannot set a specific class for the first result, at least not with pure HTML/CSS.

Comment: Of course you can, just add the class/style after insertion to the specific element.

Comment: @APAD1, if you're not able to change the html to how you need, you might be able to target adjacent elements to override the default behavior. This should let you give a property to the first item and then using something else for everything else.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358818%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

a. Use id attribute for the first results element and reset the margin.

b. Use margin-bottom for the results instead of margin-top, and reset the last element's margin if needed

c. If you have the results in a container, you can set the container's margin-top to negative value equal to the value of first result's margin top

and so on. Many ways to get this done with plain CSS. Good luck.